# Cmake multi-library scenario

Tags: c++, c, cmake

We would like to organize a `C++` project like this:

```
project/
    lib1/       (first library)
        CMakeList.txt
        src/
            lib1.c
            foo1.h
        build/
        test/       (tests)
            CMakeList.txt
            test1.c
            test2.c
    lib2/       (second library)
        CMakeList.txt
        src/
            CMakeList.txt
            os/              (OS dependent code)
                CMakeList.txt
                win32/
                    xxx.c    (win32 implementation)
                linux/
                    xxx.c    (linux implementation)
            lib2.c
            foo2.h
        build/
    include/    (shared/public headers)
        lib1/
            lib.h    (shared library header included from apps)
        lib2/
            lib.h    (shared library header -"-)
```

Please, how to write those `CMakeLists.txt` when even `lib2` should use `link1` and when e.g. `lib2` should be portable (at least Win32, Linux...)?

**Correction**: If some `CMakeList.txt` files are not on their places, please assume so. I probably forgot.

Comment: Do you really want duplicated file names in different directories? i.e. are there really 2 foo.h files and 2 lib.h files?

Comment: Well, if it's a problem, we can ban it. Is it a big problem? The thing is, that those two libraries will be 10 and developed by different people.

Comment: It is much less confusing to have them all named uniquely, regardless of whether they are mutually exclusive and equivalent.

Comment: But those two `foo.h` are local to the library, applications will use only the headers from `include/` such `#include <lib1/lib.h>` etc. Is that still a problem? If so, please assume that all headers' names are unique, no problem.

Comment: You'll also want CMakeLists.txt files in the os specific directories.  It is much clearer and more direct to conditionally include different cmake files than to having the configuration inline in the branching.

Comment: Yes, sorry, they should be there -- I'll correct the question. Thank you.

Comment: It's just clearer to know exactly what is in a file by its title, instead of having to open it up or look at its directory name.  Things like debuggers and OS shortcuts will also get confused when you name things the same.  It's less a problem in windows because it has no shortcuts, linux devs might strangle you though.

Comment: OK, changed to `foo1.h` and `foo2.h`.

Comment: @TomKerr: the fact remain that when different people / teams develop independently, name collisions on files might occur. Of course, in different directories and namespaces, it's just not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole philosophy is to start with a central CMakeLists.txt for your whole project. At this level all the targets (libs, executables) are gonna be aggregated so there will be no problem linking from lib1 to lib2 for example. If lib2 is gonna be linking to lib1, lib1 needs to be built first.

Platform specific source files should be set conditionally to some variable.
(If you need to set variable in a subdirectory and use it in a directory above, you have to set it to the cache, using CACHE FORCE etc. - see manual for `set`)

This is how you do proper out of source build - as CMake intends:

```
cd project-build
cmake ../project
```

Having separate build directories per library is not very CMake'ish (if I may say so) and would probably require
some hacks.

```
project-build/
project/
    CMakeLists.txt (whole project CMakeLists.txt)
    [
        project(MyAwesomeProject)

        include_directories(include) # allow lib1 and lib2 to include lib1/lib.h and lib2/lib.h
        add_subdirectory(lib1) # this adds target lib1
        add_subdirectory(lib2) # this adds target lib2

    ]

    lib1/       (first library)
        CMakeList.txt
        [
            add_library(lib1...)
            add_subdirectory(test)
        ]
        src/
            lib1.c
            foo1.h
        test/       (tests)
            CMakeList.txt
            test1.c
            test2.c
    lib2/       (second library)
        CMakeList.txt
        [
            add_subdirectory(src)
        ]
        src/
            CMakeList.txt
            [
                if(WIN32)
                    set(lib2_os_sources os/win32/xxx.c)
                elsif(LINUX)
                    set(lib2_os_sources os/linux/xxx.c)
                else()
                    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported OS")
                endif()
                add_library(lib2 SHARED lib2.c ${lib2_os_sources})
            ]
            os/              (OS dependent code)
                win32/
                    xxx.c    (win32 implementation)
                linux/
                    xxx.c    (linux implementation)
            lib2.c
            foo2.h
    include/    (shared/public headers)
        lib1/
            lib.h    (shared library header included from apps)
        lib2/
            lib.h    (shared library header -"-)
```

Comment: See `include_directories(include)` in the top CMakeLists.txtYou may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: you can also separately provide `include_directories(include/lib1)` and `include_directories(include/lib2)` if you do not want to use `#include <lib1/lib1.h>` but `#include <lib1.h>`. Keep in mind that this is has to be in the top CMakeLists.txt